# Memcached plugin on MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, memcached

I'd like to try new NoSQL feature in MySQL 5.6 but I am using MariaDB 10.0.2 on Debian 6 and don't fancy coming back to MySQL.

I'm wondering whether the memcached plugin has been added to MariaDB? And if not whether one can still use it as an addon?

And if not, can I use the existing Cassandra plugin of MariaDB to the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

> > I'm wondering whether the memcached plugin has been added to MariaDB?

Not yet.  But slide 24 of [mariadb-10-and-whats-new-with-the-project](http://www.slideshare.net/bytebot/mariadb-10-and-whats-new-with-the-project) mentions:

```
 Plan is to have all important features of MySQL 5.6 by the time
 MariaDB 10.1.x is released as stable - For all practical purposes
 MariaDB 10.1.x will be a drop in replacement to MySQL 5.6"
```

https://kb.askmonty.org/en/what-is-mariadb-100/

- New Features Backported from MySQL 5.6

  - New InnoDB — from MySQL 5.6.5

The thought being that the InnoDB Memcached Plugin would come along with InnoDB from 5.6.  Also see https://mariadb.com/blog/mariadb-10-vs-mysql-56-feature-comparison-update

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4674 is a request for it
  https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/126 is a patch

The source is https://github.com/MariaDB/server , this is where it would be added.

Update, add link to related issue: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12050 - "Remove unused InnoDB Memcached hooks from MariaDB Server"

Answer (score 2):

A memached storage engine existed in the past, but I don't think that it is still mantained. It probably has never been mature.

MariaDB 10 doesn't include the Memached Plugin for InnoDB, and probably it wouldn't work if you install it.

So, you don't want to switch back to MySQL? I understand, because MariaDB is more open to the community and MariaDB 10 has more interesting features. But in that case, the only thing you can do is using LevelDB instead of Memcached. LevelDB in my opinion is a good replacement for Memcached. You could also consider the HandlerSocket plugin.

But if you need to use Memcached with transactions or foreign keys, then you can't use MariaDB.

**EDIT:** I talked about the LevelDB and not Cassandra because LevelDB uses the same basic concepts as Memcached. But yes, you could also use Cassandra (if it makes sense in your use case).

Answer (score 1):

The memcached plugin will be removed from MySQL, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-memcached.html :

> **Note**
>
> The InnoDB memcached plugin is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.22;
> expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.

Meanwhile there is nothing written on the removal of the HandlerSocket of MariaDB, which offers also direct NoSQL DB Access:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/handlersocket/